# SELECT binding: clearing the options observable array sets value observable property to undefined. How to avoid it?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have a knockout viewmodel like this (farly simplified example):

```
var vm = function() {
   this.items = ko.observableArray();
   this.selectedItemValue = ko.observable(null)

   this.items.push({ value: "item1", text: "First item"});
   this.items.push({ value: "item2", text: "Second item"});
};
```

I have a Select box which is bound to these properties like this:

```
<select data-bind="value: selectedItemValue, options: items, optionsValue: 'value', optionsText: 'text'"></select>
```

When I select a value from the select box, and then after I clear the items array, my `selectedItemValue` property changes to undefined. <strike>Then, when I refill my array, and it has an item with my previously selected value, my `selectedItemValue` will be corrected.</strike>

I think this is because its source object was deleted, and I guess the string value was kind of passed by reference to the bound `selectedItemValue` observable.

How to avoid this situation? I would like <strike>to keep the selected string value</strike> the selected value observable not to change during I clear and refill my items array. This is because I refresh the array completely via ajax time to time, and this behaviour introduces some hardly fixable bugs.

UPDATE:

It seems like this behaviour is related specifically to the select binding mechanism, and it does not restore to my originally selected value, but the first item in the selectable items, which makes more sense in this case.

A [jsfiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/VfQvu/) to demonstrate my issue.

Comment: How exactly do you clear the `items` array?

Comment: @haim770, I've updated the question with jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2):

You should to use `computed` observable, which will change `selectedItemValue` only when new value is not undefined:

ViewModel:

```
    self.selectedItemValue = ko.observable(null);
    self.selectedItemValueComp = ko.computed({
        read: function() {
            return self.selectedItemValue;
        },
        write: function(newValue) {
            if (newValue) {
                self.selectedItemValue(newValue);
            }
        }
    });
```

Html:

```
<select data-bind="value: selectedItemValueComp, options: items, optionsValue: 'value', optionsText: 'text'"></select>
<button type="button" data-bind="click: clearItems">Clear select items</button>
<button type="button" data-bind="click: refillItems">Refill select items</button>

<br/>
selectedItemValueComp: <strong data-bind="text: selectedItemValueComp()"></strong>
<br/>
selectedItemValue: <strong data-bind="text: selectedItemValue"></strong>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VfQvu/3/)

Comment: Thank you that's a good workaround as well, but I've found a more elegant solution, and answered my question in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, resetting the value to undefined when options are cleared is a good and correct behaviour. For me it was problemmatic because I actually didn't want to clear the options, but to refill them, keeping the original selection if it's presented in the new items array as well.

I've found a solution in the meantime, writing my own "refill" method. I will share it here in case of anyone needs such functionality in the future.

The key part is using the `valueWillMutate` and `valueHasMutated` ko methods, which can be used to indicate that a batch change will be executed on an observable.

```
ko.observableArray.fn.refill = function (items) {
    if (!(items instanceof Array)) return this.peek().length;
    var underlyingArray = this.peek();
    this.valueWillMutate();    
    underlyingArray.splice(0, underlyingArray.length);
    ko.utils.arrayPushAll(underlyingArray, items);
    this.valueHasMutated();
    return this.peek().length;
};
```

[Here is a working fiddle demo for the solution.](http://jsfiddle.net/VfQvu/1/)